# How to remove magento breadcrumbs via the admin-panel?

Tags: php, magento

I want to remove the *breadcrumbs* from magento pages, especially from the **product detail** and **product listing** pages.

Can this be done without changing any code? Only inside the **admin-panel**?

Comment: There is no Breadcrumb in the Magento admin pages. What do you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best way is to go to:

`System --> Web --> Default Pages --> Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages`

and turn them off.

Another way ([shown here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/798)) is to create/extend the `local.xml` file inside your template directory.

e.g `/app/design/frontend/default/YOURTEMPLATE/layout/local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: not working for product detail and product listing pages

Comment: Maybe this one helps you: [remove breadcrumbs via local.xml](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/798)

Comment: well, adding another file is not exactly changing any code. Anyway, i doubt there is another solution, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear. However following information will give you an idea

1. If you are trying to add breadcrumbs in Magento admin side, well... it is not possible. Because Magento admin breadcrumbs are incomplete functionality. Of course you can see lot of instance in different controllers (that for admin) that it is settings breadcrumbs for admin side. But the sad fact is, it will not work. You cant see breadcrumbs anywhere in admin side. This is because breadcrumbs part for admin side is an uncomplete functionality. There is no specific reason for that. May be it later version, Magento will complete that functinality. Let us hope for that.

For an example, you can see breadcrumbs that is setting for `catalog` menu in admin side in this file location `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\CatalogController.php` as like this

```
 $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Catalog'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Catalog'));
```

But you can't see this breadcrumb anywhere under `catalog` menu in admin.

2. Magento frontend breadcrumbs are well structured completed functionality. By default you can see breadcrumbs in every page. Texts shown in breadcrumbs are hard-coded in core modules as well as in Magento extensions (if any). There is  no provision to control breadcrumbs through admin side. If you need to change breadcrubms, you need to find the location in which the breadcrumbs value is set and then alter it.

Check out my answer **[on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201927/magento-breadcrumbs-on-category-page/)**. This wil give you a lot of ideas

If you need to show breadcrumbs only for category pages and not for any other pages , **[you can use this extesnion](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/magneto-category-breadcrumbs)**. It is absolutely free :)

Hope that makes sense

### EDIT

So you need to remove breadcrumbs from product detail page and product list page. The solution is this.

1. create a file `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/local.xml`.
2. Put this code inside that file

   ```
    <layout>
   <!-- this part removes breadcrumbs from product view page -->
   <catalog_product_view>
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
   </catalog_product_view>
   <!-- this part removes breadcrumbs from product list pages -->
   <catalog_category_default>
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
   </catalog_category_default>
   <catalog_category_layered>
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
   </catalog_category_layered>
    </layout>
   ```

**Please note you cant remove breadcrumbs through admin side. You can do this only through code**

Comment: please read my question i do not want to show breadcrum with some setting from admin panel